# Pandas - Breaking down my data frame by columns into rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, data-cleaning

This is a project I've been trying to plow through these past few days.  We are looking at better ways to integrate financial data into our dashboards, but the software we use exports our data in a disgusting way that is not possible to plug into any type of program as its meant for a person to visually glance and get an idea.

I'm hoping to get advice on how to code it properly, but also if I am being crazy on the way to address it.  This data has already been heavily cleaned so please let me know if there is something terribly wrong:

```
                 Expense Categories Jan Actual Jan Budget Feb Actual  \
3    5600 Direct Personnel Expenses    2521.73          0    -290.57   
4           6000 Automobile Expense     909.33       1314     483.15   
5         6160 Funeral Home Expense       1072    1800.02          0   
6                  6400 Lab Expense          0          0      65.18   
9        6100 Marketing & Promotion     543.13    1850.01    1158.41
```

As well, while cleaning I pulled variables such as:

```
department = "PR"
direct_indirect = {'5600 Direct Personnel Expenses' : 'Direct Expense', etc}
```

My end goal is to include a budget summary in dashboards I have designed for each department via tableau, so I believe the best outcome will look like:

```
Expense Category  Direct/Indirect  Department   Month-Year  Actual  Budget
6400 Lab Expense    Direct Expense   PR          jan 2016     0       0
6400 Lab Expense    Direct Expense   PR          feb 2016     0       0
6400 Lab Expense    Direct Expense   PR          mar 2016     0       0
6400 Lab Expense    Direct Expense   PR          apr 2016     0       0
6400 Lab Expense    Direct Expense   PR          may 2016     0       0
```

Where I am struggling on how to complete this is I am completely unsure how to go forward by creating multiple rows in the new data frame for each expense type, separated by the fact that every two columns is a new set of months.  I feel like the only way would be to use:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
```

But I would be lost at how to iterate over each column, then assign those to a new dataframe.

Please let me know if I am missing any details you would need and I appreciate your help in working this out.

Andy

Comment: I think you want to look into multiindexing. You can get a lot of what you want by clever pivots and such.

Answer (score 2):

`melt` and `pivot_table`

```
df=df.melt('Expense Categories')
df[['Month','Type']]=df.variable.str.split(' ',expand=True)
df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Expense Categories','Month'],columns='Type',values='value').reset_index()
df

Out[1176]: 
Type              Expense Categories Month   Actual   Budget
0     5600 Direct Personnel Expenses   Feb  -290.57      NaN
1     5600 Direct Personnel Expenses   Jan  2521.73     0.00
2            6000 Automobile Expense   Feb   483.15      NaN
3            6000 Automobile Expense   Jan   909.33  1314.00
4         6100 Marketing & Promotion   Feb  1158.41      NaN
5         6100 Marketing & Promotion   Jan   543.13  1850.01
6          6160 Funeral Home Expense   Feb     0.00      NaN
7          6160 Funeral Home Expense   Jan  1072.00  1800.02
8                   6400 Lab Expense   Feb    65.18      NaN
9                   6400 Lab Expense   Jan     0.00     0.00
```

We almost get there then

```
df['department']='PR'
df['Direct/Indirect'] = 'Direct Expense'
df['Month-Year'] = df['Month'] + str(2016)
df
Out[1182]: 
Type              Expense Categories Month   Actual   Budget department  \
0     5600 Direct Personnel Expenses   Feb  -290.57      NaN         PR   
1     5600 Direct Personnel Expenses   Jan  2521.73     0.00         PR   
2            6000 Automobile Expense   Feb   483.15      NaN         PR   
3            6000 Automobile Expense   Jan   909.33  1314.00         PR   
4         6100 Marketing & Promotion   Feb  1158.41      NaN         PR   
5         6100 Marketing & Promotion   Jan   543.13  1850.01         PR   
6          6160 Funeral Home Expense   Feb     0.00      NaN         PR   
7          6160 Funeral Home Expense   Jan  1072.00  1800.02         PR   
8                   6400 Lab Expense   Feb    65.18      NaN         PR   
9                   6400 Lab Expense   Jan     0.00     0.00         PR   
Type Direct/Indirect Month-Year  
0     Direct Expense    Feb2016  
1     Direct Expense    Jan2016  
2     Direct Expense    Feb2016  
3     Direct Expense    Jan2016  
4     Direct Expense    Feb2016  
5     Direct Expense    Jan2016  
6     Direct Expense    Feb2016  
7     Direct Expense    Jan2016  
8     Direct Expense    Feb2016  
9     Direct Expense    Jan2016
```

Comment: That's a neat way to do it!

Comment: @unutbu surprised by your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape your DataFrame by using [`df.columns.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Expense Categories': ['5600 Direct Personnel Expenses', '6000 Automobile Expense', '6160 Funeral Home Expense', '6400 Lab Expense', '6100 Marketing & Promotion'], 'Feb Actual': [-290.57, 483.15, 0.0, 65.18, 1158.41], 'Jan Actual': [2521.73, 909.33, 1072.0, 0.0, 543.13], 'Jan Budget': [0.0, 1314.0, 1800.02, 0.0, 1850.01]})

df = df.set_index('Expense Categories')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
df.columns.names = ['Month-Year',None]
df = df.stack('Month-Year')
df = df.reset_index()
df['Direct/Indirect'] = 'Direct Expense'
df['Department'] = 'PR'
df['Month-Year'] = df['Month-Year'] + ' 2016'

with pd.option_context('display.width', sys.maxsize):
    print(df)
```

yields

```
               Expense Categories Month-Year   Actual   Budget Direct/Indirect Department
0  5600 Direct Personnel Expenses   Feb 2016  -290.57      NaN  Direct Expense         PR
1  5600 Direct Personnel Expenses   Jan 2016  2521.73     0.00  Direct Expense         PR
2         6000 Automobile Expense   Feb 2016   483.15      NaN  Direct Expense         PR
3         6000 Automobile Expense   Jan 2016   909.33  1314.00  Direct Expense         PR
4       6160 Funeral Home Expense   Feb 2016     0.00      NaN  Direct Expense         PR
5       6160 Funeral Home Expense   Jan 2016  1072.00  1800.02  Direct Expense         PR
6                6400 Lab Expense   Feb 2016    65.18      NaN  Direct Expense         PR
7                6400 Lab Expense   Jan 2016     0.00     0.00  Direct Expense         PR
8      6100 Marketing & Promotion   Feb 2016  1158.41      NaN  Direct Expense         PR
9      6100 Marketing & Promotion   Jan 2016   543.13  1850.01  Direct Expense         PR
```

---

**Explanation**:

```
df = df.set_index('Expense Categories')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
df.columns.names = ['Month-Year',None]
```

These lines create a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) for the column index. It splits the Month from the Acrtual/Budget part of the column labels. `set_index` is used here to hide the `Expense Categories` column from the `str.split` operation. At this point `df` looks like this:

```
Month-Year                          Feb      Jan         
                                 Actual   Actual   Budget
Expense Categories                                       
5600 Direct Personnel Expenses  -290.57  2521.73     0.00
6000 Automobile Expense          483.15   909.33  1314.00
6160 Funeral Home Expense          0.00  1072.00  1800.02
6400 Lab Expense                  65.18     0.00     0.00
6100 Marketing & Promotion      1158.41   543.13  1850.01
```

Now we can move the `Jan/Feb` (or, more precisely, the "Month-Year" level of the index ) into its own column using `stack`:

```
df = df.stack('Month-Year')
```

yields

```
                                            Actual   Budget
Expense Categories             Month-Year                  
5600 Direct Personnel Expenses Feb         -290.57      NaN
                               Jan         2521.73     0.00
6000 Automobile Expense        Feb          483.15      NaN
                               Jan          909.33  1314.00
6160 Funeral Home Expense      Feb            0.00      NaN
                               Jan         1072.00  1800.02
6400 Lab Expense               Feb           65.18      NaN
                               Jan            0.00     0.00
6100 Marketing & Promotion     Feb         1158.41      NaN
                               Jan          543.13  1850.01
```